# How to update(by merging) edmx without override the model classes in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I am developing an application in asp.net mvc. I use entity framework as ORM. I have a problem. To use javascript unobstrusive validation, I need to add annotation to model objects. For example; [Required], [EMailAddress]. But when we add something to the database and update it, all model classes are override, and all annotations disappear. Or, as soon as you open edmx, automatic model classes are automatically override. How can I solve this problem. There are dozens of screens and classes, the slightest change in edmx erases the annotation in all classes, causing huge waste of time.

```
// <auto-generated>

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MerinosSurvey.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Surveys
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Surveys()
    {
        this.SurveyQuestions = new HashSet<SurveyQuestions>();
        this.SurveyCustomers = new HashSet<SurveyCustomers>();
    }

    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Plase enter survey name.")]
    public string SurveyName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter survey description.")]
    public string SurveyDescription { get; set; }

    // [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]

    public System.DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SurveyQuestions> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SurveyCustomers> SurveyCustomers { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Editted for
Metadata**

**Surveys Partial & Metadata**

```
 //PartialClass
 [MetadataType(typeof(SurveyMetadata))]
 public partial class Surveys
{
}
//Metadata
 public partial class SurveyMetadata
{
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen anket adını giriniz.")]
    public string SurveyName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen anket açıklamasını giriniz.")]
    public string SurveyDescription { get; set; }

    // [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]

    public System.DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SurveyQuestionMetadata> SurveyQuestionMetadatas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SurveyCustomerMetadata> SurveyCustomerMetadatas { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

**GetData Ajax Event**

```
  // GET: Survey
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        using (MerinosSurveyEntities entity = new MerinosSurveyEntities())
        {
            List<Surveys> surveys = entity.Surveys.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Status)
                .OrderBy(x => x.SurveyId).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = surveys }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

How I should change my GetData event.And what list should go to the client side??

Comment: Don't use EF entity classes in your views. Create view model classes for the controller<->view interaction, including validation attributes. The MVC tutorials love to keep things flat but that's just to reduce complexity for the sake of demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Practice is, use ViewModel[Not Entity/Model classes] to manipulate / play at Client Side.

So use ViewModel, Inherit Model classes and then use Annotations
For eg. 
    Public class ViewModelClass: ModelClass
       {
         [Required("First Name is Required")]
         Public String FirstName {get; set;}
       }

Comment: So how can I fix this with minimal modification, just inheriting new classes will solve my job in a simple way.

Comment: @MehmetŞükrüMUMBUÇOĞLU Please see my example, Create a new class, inherit it from Model class or copy paste all properties from Model to This class, now add your annotations. Because tomorrow you are going to face serious troubles, if you are going to use Model classes only, that time u need to use non model classes

Comment: As of now, I have 10 tables. The first phase of the project has been completed. In the meantime, I can make changes. I do not need much change, I think the Survey table will change as SurveyViewModel. Also, since fk relationships between tables are certain when creating tables, the model classes are also designed automatically accordingly.

Comment: @shyamsundarsinghtomar So how can I fix this with minimal modification, just inheriting new classes will solve my job in a simple way. Forexample two hour  Ihave 10 table.5 of them relation table.

Comment: My approach is more flexible, you have take wrong decisions earlier, I understand it's pain, but believe me , it will save you from disastrous. You can try this too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation . Check Metadata part.

Comment: Hope it helps you. Vote it if it helps

Comment: @shyamsundarsinghtomar I created 2 files named one metadata and one partial class. I added 10 metadata classes for 10 tables in them. I added all the fields in the model class while copying to the metadata class. I wonder if I'm doing it wrong. I added all fields, constructor, list definitions, all in metadata class. Is this a correct method because fk relationships in the database have been moved into model classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206427/discussion-between-mehmet-sukru-mumbucoglu-and-shyam-sundar-singh-tomar).

Comment: thnaks brother. If you like the question you can upvote  my question

Answer (score 0):

For do such thing you can use partial classes and use "ModelMetadataType" in .net core annotation above your class.
lets do it in code:
this is your model that is created in edmx:

```
public partial class Student{
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

first of all you have to create a partial class in another file with same name as student class and be careful its name space should be same as above class. (classes must be out of edmx file)

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(StudentMetaData))]
public partial class Student{

}
```

and at the end you must create your metadata class like this:

```
public class StudentMetaData{
     [Display(name="First Name")]
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

now you can update your edmx file without changing the data annotations in your metadata classes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: someone else asked my problem on [this page](https://forums.asp.net/t/1885808.aspx?Update+edmx+file+without+effecting+currently+generated+model). And **EF generates partial classes by default. So you can put your logic in a "buddy class" that does not get overwritten.** writes. Does the Entity framework really create partial view model classes?

Comment: Entity framework doesn't create "view model" classes at all. They're ***entity*** classes.

Comment: you can create a copy of your class and do like as told easily. if you encountered any problem we can solve it easily

Comment: @Jafarashrafi Should I make the metadata class as a class or an interface? Does this matter to me?

Comment: @Jafarashrafi I also want to ask one more thing. I should add all the attributes in the entity model class to the metadata class, right? Including lists. If I don't add the lists, everything will be broken on the client side. For example SurveyCustomers list in my above model

Comment: yo don't need to add all properties in your meta data class. you can use lists as you used before if you add or not. meta data class is a Metadata and your main class is the one that created in edmx

Comment: okay ok. For example, a function that I bring to the screen with ajax is getData. Do I need to change this? So should client side (in View) be metedata objects? For example  **`// GET: Survey
        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            using (MerinosSurveyEntities entity = new MerinosSurveyEntities())
            {
                List<Surveys> surveys = entity.Surveys.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Status)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.SurveyId).ToList();
                return Json(new { data = surveys }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
`**

Comment: Remember that metadata class is just a meta data and it describes some information about properties or classes and it never effect your business and even get or post. your main class is responsible for that. you have to never write any business in metadata class

Answer (score 0):

Working from memory at the moment, but the EF classes are always partial so create another partial implementation of the same class, then add the Interface and Metadatatype binding to that.

```
// Entity Framework Model
public partial class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

// Your Interface with data annotations
public interface IUser
{
    [Required]
    string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    string Password { get; set; }
}

// Partial Model appling the interface to the entity model
[MetadataType(typeof(IUser))]
public partial class User : IUser
{
}
```

Under this approach, in the future, you only need to worry about updating your interface should you add new properties

Comment: Should I make the metadata class as a class or an interface? Does this matter to me?

Comment: I would create it as an interface since it separates concerns between the entity object and the data annotations whilst still allow you to consume the entity object.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the generated CS files (the one's with your table names) that you've already added your annotations to, to another folder, then overwrite the newly generated ones, I do it this way and shall continue to until there's a more hassle-free way to do it.